# Is there an equivalent of SimpleTest's "partial mocks" in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit, simpletest

I'm trying to migrate a bunch of tests from SimpleTest to [PHPUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit) and I was wondering if there is an equivalent for SimpleTest's [partial mocks](http://www.simpletest.org/en/partial_mocks_documentation.html).

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation which suggests that this feature is available, but it occurred to me that I could just use a subclass. Is this a good or bad idea?

```
class StuffDoer {
    protected function doesLongRunningThing() {
        sleep(10);
        return "stuff";
    }
    public function doStuff() {
        return $this->doesLongRunningThing();
    }
}

class StuffDoerTest {
    protected function doesLongRunningThing() {
        return "test stuff";
    }
}

class StuffDoerTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testStuffDoer() {
        $sd = new StuffDoerTest();
        $result = $sd->doStuff();
        $this->assertEquals($result, "test stuff");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From reading the linked page, a SimpleTest partial mock seems to be a mock where only some of the methods are overridden. If this is correct, that functionality is handled by a normal PHPUnit mock.

Inside a `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`, you create a mock with

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Class_To_Mock');
```

Which creates an mock instance where all methods do nothing and return null. If you want to only override some of the methods, the second parameter to `getMock` is an array of methods to override.

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Class_To_Mock', array('insert', 'update'));
```

will create an mock instance of `Class_To_Mock` with the `insert` and `update` functions removed, ready for their return values to be specified.

This information is in the [phpunit docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects).

**Note**, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083956/1319821) shows more up to date code examples, for PHPUnit versions starting 5.4

Answer (score 24):

[`PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::getMock` is deprecated since phpunit 5.4](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/aa47f767c5ecadab9df0862c34398e4ee582bb56/ChangeLog-5.4.md). We can use `setMethods` instead.

> setMethods(array $methods) can be called on the Mock Builder object to specify the methods that are to be replaced with a configurable test double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed. If you call setMethods(null), then no methods will be replaced.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

```
$observer = $this->getMockBuilder(Observer::class)
                 ->setMethods(['update'])
                 ->getMock();
```

Note that the above `getMock` is `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockBuilder::getMock`. (phpunit5.6)

Comment: setMethods() is also depricated

Comment: `setMethods` has been deprecated in PHPUnit 8.x, you can use `onlyMethods` now, more info [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3687).

Answer (score 6):

The method `setMethods` was deprecated. Now it works:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(ClassToMock::class)
    ->onlyMethods(['insert', 'update'])
    ->getMock();
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think PHPUnit supports partial mocks for the system under test.  If you're trying to isolate methods then I'm sure your implementation works - I've done that too.

However, I try to avoid doing this, for a couple of reasons.

First, it couples your test very tightly to the internal implementation of the class.  Do you really care whether a method called `doesLongRunningThing` was called, or is it more important that the "LongRunningThing" got done?

Second, when I run into this it always makes me wonder whether I've got one class doing the job of two.  An *extract class* refactoring might be in order.  The testing becomes much easier if `doesLongRunningThing()` becomes its own class, even with a single method.

I believe the solution is to inject the services your SUT depends on (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  This also makes the `DoesLongRunningThing` implementation more testable.

Without jumping into interfaces, here's what I would do:

```
class DoesLongRunningThing {
    public function execute() {
        sleep(10);
        return "stuff";
    }
}

class StuffDoer {
    protected $doesLongRunningThing;

    public function setLongRunningThinger(DoesLongRunningThing $obj) {
        $this->doesLongRunningThing = $obj;
    }

    public function doStuff() {
        return $this->doesLongRunningThing->execute();
    }
}
```

Now it's easy to mock:

```
class StuffDoerTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testStuffDoer() {
        $dlrtMock = $this->getMock('DoesLongRunningThing');
        $dlrtMock->expects($this->any())->will($this->returnValue("test stuff"));

        $sd = new StuffDoer();
        $sd->setLongRunningThinger($dlrtMock);
        $result = $sd->doStuff();
        $this->assertEquals($result, "test stuff");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think PHPUnit is just a tool, and it doesn't care about system under test (it's a tool user's deal). According to Brenton's answer, PHPUnit _supports_ "partial mocks". Starting after the first sentence your answer is perfect (+1 for it).

Answer (score -1):

It could be that the class you are mocking is not in scope (I had this issue). When resolved, I was able to mock one function and test the actual logic of another.

```
$mockController = $this->getMockBuilder('ControllerClassName')
                       ->setMethods(['functionToMock'])
                       ->getMock();

$result = $mockController->anotherFunction();
$this->assertEquals(true, $result);
```